# PHP Imap parser

Tags: php, email, parsing, imap

Before I ask my question I'd like to inform you that I did indeed search before going here, however with bad luck.

I am looking for a class which let's me connect to an email account using Imap, and parses the emails. I do know how to connect to an account, and to receive emails but I am looking for an easy class that allows me to connect and get my emails sorted nicely back to me.

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short words:

1. install php-imap module
2. use the php imap_* functions to do what you want

And more specific:

You can find an installation-guide and a list of all possible functions here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

If you need a libary, give this a try: https://github.com/tedious/Fetch or https://dev.horde.org/imap_client/index.php

Comment: My bad if I have not been clear but I did this, I'm looking for a parser class which allows me to sort everything nice and clean. Cleaner than the basic imap functions.

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: I will be giving fetch a try, thank you.